# POX SDN py.py- how did it start?

Tags: pox

I'm learning to run some of the scripts from POX SDN. Reference https://github.com/noxrepo/pox

Like to ask py.py is started? There is nothing like c program that has a main() and code starts to run from there. In the py.py script, it is all def and class. The last def is "def launch() which I never see any lines calling for launch()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what script do you want to run. And what kind of controller.

For example if you want to run of_tutorial.py of pox controller:

```
./pox.py log.level --DEBUG misc.of_tutorial.py
```